# MVVM with controller

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, mvvm, controller

I am developing a game in Silverlight. I have my game flow ready and graphics have also been taken care of. Now while searching for a perfect back-end design i came across MVVM. Went through various tutorials and have an understanding of how it would work with a single module. However in my plan i want to load/call multiple views at user input. Is there a way a single controller can handle my application workflow. It has been mentioned in the following post:
[Controllers in MVVM, How to get info from viewmodel to it's controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471881/controllers-in-mvvm-how-to-get-info-from-viewmodel-to-its-controller)
But nowhere i could find an example. Can someone provide a dummy application, reading material, block diagrams?

Comment: So basically you have single ViewModel which able to serve different Views?

Comment: No i have different Modules, and One Controller. Each module has its own Presenter, View and VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use framework to help what you're trying to do, otherwise you will end up write tons of code.

I have create similar application (show multiple view to user at a time) and I use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) to help me. If you want to learn about it, you can walk through [Prism Training Kit](http://prismtk.codeplex.com/).