# What parameters should I pass to my ViewModel's constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm pretty novice to WPF/MVVM and trying to understand this pattern. I'm exploring this MVVM application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Author created `Customer` class which is stored in `Model` folder and `CustomerRepository` class which is stored in `DataAccess` folder

`CustomerRepository` contains methods that 'do stuff', for example `static List<Customer> LoadCustomers(string customerDataFile)` I.e. we can't say that `CustomerRepository` is pure model file, it's also kind of utility file.

From another hand `CustomerRepository` stores important data `readonly List<Customer> _customers;` and we know that we should store such kind of data in model!

Well I would say that `CustomerRepository` is mixing things - it's a model file that contains some utility methods inside it.

The problem is that `CustomerRepository` instance is passed to ViewModel `public AllCustomersViewModel(CustomerRepository customerRepository)`. Now viewModel contains something that it shouldn't, in particular it can force `CustomerRepository` to reload stuff etc.

In my opinion this is agains MVVM pattern, I think that **ViewModel should only contain references to model files** all utility classes and methods to **manipulate model files should be in other places**.

Am I right or wrong? **Is it ok to pass class that offers some services on model (can reload/refhresh model etc.) to ViewModel?** I.e. where should be so-called `service layer`, is it ok to have it in ViewModel?

Comment: If to pass an interface instead of the repository class, the view model will not be able to reload stuff and it will call only those methods which are exposed in the interface.

Comment: @vorrtex it's always possible to do things via reflection (if it exist in c#..)

Comment: I found this video very helpful when learning MVVM, you should have a look at it - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKfpvs7ZIyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK,  there are two widespreas treatments of the MVVM pattern.

The first, which you seem to be more familiar with, includes 4 components: View, Model, ViewModel and Controller. Here, ViewModel contains only UI logic and exposes events to Controller which serves for synchronization between ViewModel and Model.

The second, which is used in the article, simply merges ViewModel and Controller into ViewModel. BTW, Martin Fowler describes this case: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html

The choice depends on personal preferences as I see it.

Comment: Odd, never heard of the MVVMC pattern.

Comment: @Will Then you should have googled: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471881/controllers-in-mvvm-how-to-get-info-from-viewmodel-to-its-controller), [2](http://trelford.com/blog/post/MVMMC-e28093-MVVM-grows-a-Controller.aspx)

Comment: @Will I'm sorry, wan't it what you've asked?

Comment: Didn't ask anything; was making a statement.  Dunno.  I can appreciate attempts to adhere to SRP and to keep your VM thin (they definitely can end up bloated messes!), but I'm not sure about tacking on the C at this point.  I'd need to read more about it (a Q here and a minimal blog post don't cut it).

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong in your assumption that "ViewModel should only contain references to model files".

ViewModel can reference anything it needs, as long as it isn't a view.

It is very common to inject services into a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I believe in most MVVM application you'll find the same. Actually ViewModel is aware of communication with services, repositories, directly or not directly depends on application design so this is pretty fine. Moreover VM should be able to force reloading data and so on to reflect requested by UI changes. ViewModel decoupled from View by Commands and Bindings, by exposing commands ViewModel able to handle any specific command and then request/update a new data from services, whatever.

Comment: well then the question is - where "service layer" should be? i think "model" should be "clean", so I should extract services from it...

Comment: ViewModel is not a model, ViewModel is aware of model, encapsulates some Model-related logic and able to work with a model (change it). Services could be a separate layer but ViewModel just keep references to services which it need to work with (services injected via constructor )